# Solving a two dimensional non-homogenous linear recurrence

Tags: co.combinatorics, recurrences

How one can solve the following recurrence:
\begin{align} 
X[i,0] &=0 \quad \forall i =1,\ldots, m\\
X[m,n] &= a_n X[m,n-1]+b_n \sum_{i=k_m}^{m-1}X[i,i] +c_n 
\end{align}

Where $a_i\ge 1 ,~ 0 \le c_i , b_i <1, k_i \ge 1$ are constants for all $i =  1,\ldots, n$.

Comment: The expression after the dots is surely mistyped. I edited it, but maybe i misunderstood your intentions.

Comment: Where did this arise?

Comment: It arises in a problem called "online dynamic TCP acknowledgement". There is an algorithm proposed by Buchbinder that uses a special case of this update rule. Namely, $a_i = a_k, b_i = b_k$ and $c_i=c_k$ for all $i \neq k$. This is a generalization for the weighted dynamic TCP ack problem, where each packet has a weight that can define the delay penalty.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $n$ is a nonnegative integer although this should be clearly stated in the question. Even in simplest cases this recurrence  is indeterminate, because  it does not say anying about the terms $X[m,n]$, $m-n\neq 0,1$.

Suppose that $a_n=1$, $k_n=n-1$, $c_n=0$. The recurrence then reads

$$X[n,n]-X[n-1,n-1]=X[n,n-1]. $$

This implies

$$ X[n,n]= X[0,0]+ X[1,0]+X[2,1]+\cdots  + X[n,n-1]. $$

The terms  $X[m,n]$, $m-n\neq 0$ can be chosen arbitrarily.  I believe there is some typo in the recurrence relation.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I'll try to fix it now.